# How to remove the separator between values of a multi value field in a Views result?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I'm working on a D8 project. I have a webform with multiple fields and one of those is a taxonomy term. The taxonomy term consist of the title and a file upload field. The admin uploads a file in the taxonomy, and in the webform selects which file/s should be visible to the end user.

In order to display those files to the user I created a webform submission view where I get the specific field. The point is that the field might return multiple values (taxonomy terms) which are separated by comma.

How can I remove that comma? In D7 you could choose the separator in mulivalue field but now I can't find something similar.

EDIT: 
The last idea was to change the output in the template file.
So in views-view-field.html.twig I try to replace the comma with space in the  output of the field.

```
{% set output = output|replace({(',') : (' '),}) %}
```

What I get is the html of the view with a lot of debug informations but the view is not rendered as it should.
I get something like <!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- THEME HOOK: 'webform_element_base_html' --> <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS: *

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I'm not sure if is the best, but it works.

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables){
  $view = $variables['view'];

  if ($view->id() == 'VIEW_ID'){
    $output = str_replace(',', '', $variables['output']);
    $variables['output'] = \Drupal\views\Render\ViewsRenderPipelineMarkup::create($output);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works but it wipes out all commas that are in the content of the field as well.

Comment: Yes because it replaces the commas. I couldn't find any other working option!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing `<!-- THEME DEBUG -->` because Twig debug is enabled in either your `sites/default/services.yml` or `sites/development.services.yml`. You can disable Twig debug as follows:

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: false
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but the point is that in the block I still get printed the html as a string and not the files as I should.

Answer (score 1):

You can change or remove the separator from the view configuration of the field:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting the solution provided by @Achraf should've worked as I've been using the same thing for a decade! Surprisingly, the "MULTIPLE VALUES HANDLING" option is missing if I check "Use entity field rendering" at the view field option while using Drupal 9.4.8.

I've tried to improve the code snippet provided by @Ismini. In the following, apart from checking the Views ID, I'm also restricting it to a SPECIFIC DISPLAY & most importantly for me, to a SPECIFIC FIELD.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_field().
 */
function my_template_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view */
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() === 'my_views_id' && $view->current_display === 'my_current_display' && $variables['field']->field === 'my_field') {
    $output = str_replace(',', '', $variables['output']);
    $variables['output'] = \Drupal\views\Render\ViewsRenderPipelineMarkup::create($output);
  }
}
```